# Does Python have comments that cover only part of a line?

Tags: python, eclipse, intellij-idea, syntax, comments

In Java, for example, one can say:

```
public void do(/*when*/time, /*subject*/principal){...}
```

or, similarly, when refactoring:

```
public void do(/*when*/time, /*principal*/){...}
```

Does Python have an equivalent facility whereby one can comment not a whole line, but just a part of it such that interpreter doesn't get confused?

If so, what are the shortcut keys to activate this functionality in PyDev and PyCharm?

Thank you.

Comment: It does not.  Python only has single-line, `#`-to-EOL comments.

Comment: As [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) recommends a maximum line length of 80, I don't think it is very pythonic to include comments in the same line of a command.

Comment: Even PEP-8 acknowledges that longer line lengths are fine for your *own* code; the shorter lengths are only required for code being added to the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can break your code into multiple lines and use it this way:

```
def foo():
   return {'foo':'bar',
           #'bar':'baz',
           'boo':'faz'}
```

Same logic applies to function parameters and anywhere u can break code into multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Valid python comments are:

```
# this is the first comment
spam = 1  # and this is the second comment
          # ... and now a third!
text = "# This is not a comment because it's inside quotes."
''' multi-line 
comment using 3 quotes '''
```

---

> *Comments in Python start with the hash character, `#`, and extend to the
>   end of the physical line. A **comment may appear at the start of a line
>   or following whitespace or code, but not within a string literal**. A
>   hash character within a string literal is just a hash character. Since
>   comments are to clarify code and are not interpreted by `Python`.*

Src:

[An informal introduction to python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#an-informal-introduction-to-python)